# Using meta-programming to calculate the log2 but `compilation terminated`

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I'm new to TMP and I wrote a program using meta-programming to calculate the **log2**. I wrote a template struct `power2` to calculate the power, a template class `log2arr` with an array in it to save the result, and a embedded template struct `log2` to calculate log2 values.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i>
struct power2
{
    enum
    {
        value = (1 << i)
    };
};

template <int n>
class log2arr
{
    int arr[n];

    template <int i>
    struct log2
    {
        log2<i - 1> _arr;
        enum
        {
            value = log2<i - 1>::value + (power2<log2<i - 1>::value>::value == i)
        };
        void print()
        {
            _arr.print();
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
        }
        void set()
        {
            _arr.set();
            arr[i] = value;
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct log2<1>
    {
        enum
        {
            value = 1
        };
        void print() {}
        void set() {}
    };

  public:
    int *getArr()
    {
        log2<n>().set();
        return arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    log2arr<4> a = log2arr<4>();
    for(auto i : a.getArr()){
        cout << i;
    }
}
```

But the compiler only told me `compilation terminated.`

What does it mean? How can I solve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a better compiler that gives you proper errors without ICE'ing. If you want quick access to many of them, try an online service like https://godbolt.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems and I'll show some of they, in no particular order.

(1) no full specializations are allowed inside a struct/class; so your can't full specialize `log2` inside `log2arr`.

You can migrate `log2` outside `log2arr` or, if you really want maintain it inside `log2arr`, you can transform the full specialization in an equivalent partial specialization (legal inside a struct/class); by example, as follows

```
  template <int I, typename = std::true_type>
  struct log2
   {
     // body of the struct
   };

  template <int I>
  struct log2<I, std::integral_constant<bool, I == 1>>
   {
     // body of the struct specialization
   };
```

(2) if you return a `int *` from `getArr()`, you loose the information regarding the array inside `log2Arr` class; so doesn't work the range based for loop (`for(auto i : a.getArr())`).

Unfortunately you can't return a C-style array (you can't return `arr` itself).

But you're using C++11 or newer (you tagged only C++ but you're using range based for loop, so you're using at least C++11) so I strongly suggest you to define `arr` as a `std::array<int, N>`, not as C-style array (not `int arr[N]`). And I strongly suggest you to return a reference to `arr` itself (with a `std::array` you can do it)

```
   private:
      using arrT = std::array<int, N>;

      arrT arr {};

      // ...

   public:

      arrT & getArr ()
       { /* ... */ return arr; }
```

and I also suggest to add a `getArr()` for `const` objects

```
  arrT const & getArr () const
   { /* ... */ return arr; }
```

(3) you can't manage the `arr` array (not static member of `log2Arr`) inside a method of the embedded structure `log2`

```
    void set()
    {
        _arr.set();
        arr[i] = value; // <--- arr is inaccessible
    }
```

A possible solution is pass `arr` as reference, so

```
    void set (arrT & a) // arrT = std::array<int, N>
     {
        _arr.set(a);
        a[i] = value;
     }
```

and (in `log2<1>`)

```
    void set (arrT &) {}
```

Obviously you have to call `set()` passing `arr` as argument, so

```
log2<N>().set(arr)
```

(4) the initialization of `arr` inside `getArr()` is a bad idea (IMHO) because you initialize `arr` every time you call `getArr()`.

Moreover: you can't use `arr` inside another method (if you want to add another one) without initializing it inside the other method.

Suggestion: initialize `arr`, one time for all, inside an explicit costructor; by example

```
  log2arr ()
   { log2<N>().set(arr); }
```

so your `getArr()` methods simply becomes

```
  arrT & getArr ()
   { return arr; }

  arrT const & getArr () const
   { return arr; }
```

(5) with `log2<I>` that initialize `arr[I]` and `log<1>` that initialize nothing, your `int arr[N]` contains `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` values that are not inizialized.

You can initialize those values to zero writing

```
  int arr[N] {};
```

or (using `std::array<int, N>`)

```
  using arrT = std::array<int, N>;

  arrT arr {};
  //       ^^  <--- initialize all to zero
```

but you have to decide how to initialize in `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`

(6) there is no needs of initialize `a` as follows

```
log2arr<4> a = log2arr<4>();
```

You can simply write

```
log2arr<4> a;
```

### ---------------------------------------

The following is the code modified

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int I>
struct power2
 { enum { value = (1 << I) }; };

template <int N>
class log2arr
 {
   private:
      using arrT = std::array<int, N>;

      arrT arr {};

      template <int I, typename = std::true_type>
      struct log2
       {
         log2<I-1> _arr;

         enum { value =   log2<I-1>::value
                        + (power2<log2<I-1>::value>::value == I) };

         void print ()
          { _arr.print(); std::cout << value << std::endl; }

         void set (arrT & a)
          { _arr.set(a); a[I] = value; }
       };

      template <int I>
      struct log2<I, std::integral_constant<bool, I == 1>>
       {
         enum { value = 1 };

         void print() {}
         void set(arrT &) {}
       };

   public:
      log2arr ()
       { log2<N>().set(arr); }

      arrT & getArr ()
       { return arr; }

      arrT const & getArr () const
       { return arr; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   log2arr<4> a;

   for ( auto i : a.getArr() )
      std::cout << i;

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```